# can't print txt file correctly

Tags: c, file, scanf, feof

Hi i have this text file, where the first column in a character the 2nd and the third one is an integer.. but I'm not able to read and print the values correctley.

So this the file am trying to read:

```
c 6
o 4 3
o 2 4
o 3 2
o 1 1
o 3 3
```

And here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 6

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int i;
  int M[N];
  int U[N];
  char c ;
  FILE* fichier = NULL;

  fichier = fopen("pb1.txt","r");

if(fichier!= NULL )
  { 
    while(!feof(fichier))   
    {
    fscanf(fichier, "%c %d %d", &c, &M[i], &U[i]); 

    printf("%c %d %d \n", c, M[i],U[i]);
    }

  }
}
```

This is what the output looks like

```
c 6 1472131424 
o 4 3 

 4 3 
o 2 4 

 2 4 
o 3 2 

 3 2 
o 1 1 

 1 1 
o 3 3 

 3 3
```

I have no clue why it gives me this. thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see here, is you use the value of `i` uninitialized. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, `i` is an automatic local variable and unless intialized explicitly, will have an indeterminate value. Attempt to use that will lead to UB.

Also, you have never increased the value of `i` which is supposed to be used as the index for storing and printing the values.

Lastly, always check the return value of `scanf()` and family to ensure the success, before you try to use the scanned value.

That said, Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)